# JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

What is the correct way to pull out just the path from a URL using JavaScript?

Example:
I have URL
http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top
but I would just like to get this portion
*/account/search*

I am using jQuery if there is anything there that can be leveraged.

Answer (score 571, accepted):

There is a property of the built-in [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object that will provide that for the current window.

```
// If URL is http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top

window.location.pathname // /account/search

// For reference:

window.location.host     // www.somedomain.com (includes port if there is one)
window.location.hostname // www.somedomain.com
window.location.hash     // #top
window.location.href     // http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top
window.location.port     // (empty string)
window.location.protocol // http:
window.location.search   // ?filter=a
```

---

### Update, use the same properties for any URL:

It turns out that this schema is being standardized as an interface called [**URLUtils**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils), and guess what?  Both the existing `window.location` object **and anchor elements** implement the interface.

**So you can use the same properties above for *any* URL** — just create an anchor with the URL and access the properties:

```
var el = document.createElement('a');
el.href = "http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top";

el.host        // www.somedomain.com (includes port if there is one[1])
el.hostname    // www.somedomain.com
el.hash        // #top
el.href        // http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top
el.pathname    // /account/search
el.port        // (port if there is one[1])
el.protocol    // http:
el.search      // ?filter=a
```

**[1]:** Browser support for the properties that include port is not consistent, See: http://jessepollak.me/chrome-was-wrong-ie-was-right

**This works in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox**. I do not have versions of Internet Explorer to test, so please test yourself with the JSFiddle example.

### [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nchaves/vMrjs/2/)

There's also a coming [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.URL) object that will offer this support for URLs themselves, without the anchor element.  Looks like no stable browsers support it at this time, but it is said to be coming in Firefox 26.  [When you think you might have support for it, try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nchaves/nZqUr/1/).

Comment: OP asked for "a URL", not "the window's current URL".  What if you have a url as a string?

Comment: @JoshNoe Turns out you can now use the same properties on anchor elements.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the nice information. I tested with IE 9 and IE 8 (use IE 9 to simulate) both works. Of course works with Chrome and Firefox latest version :)

Answer (score 71):

```
window.location.href.split('/');
```

Will give you an array containing all the URL parts, which you can access like a normal array.

Or an ever more elegant solution suggested by @Dylan, with only the path parts:

```
window.location.pathname.split('/');
```

Comment: window.location.pathname.split('/'); is a more elegant solution in most cases if you are trying to access the different sections of the URL beyod the standard protocol and www etc.

Comment: window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(function(v) { return v; }); will remove  empty elements for Javascript 1.6 and above.

Comment: @DhavalDesai We can now also do window.location.pathname.split('/').filter( e => e )

Answer (score 37):

If this is the **current** url use **window.location.pathname** otherwise use this regular expression:

```
var reg = /.+?:\/\/.+?(\/.+?)(?:#|\?|$)/;
var pathname = reg.exec( 'http://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top' )[1];
```

Comment: Almost perfect -- but unlike window.location.pathname it does not include the drive letter in the pathname on Windows.

Comment: For a regex which works even when there's not a pathname, use: ```/.+?\:\/\/.+?(\/.+?)?(?:#|\?|)?$/```

Answer (score 25):

There is a useful Web API method called [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.somedomain.com/account/search?filter=a#top');
console.log(url.pathname.split('/').slice(1)); // drop the leading slash
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search)
console.log("filter:",params.get("filter"))
```

Comment: unfortunate to new if you need to support old browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=URL()

Comment: @nikelone https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js

Answer (score 6):

If you have an abstract URL string (not from the current `window.location`), you can use this trick:

```
let yourUrlString = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

let parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = yourUrlString;

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

Thanks to [jlong](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561#file-uri-js)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to get parts of an URL that you have stored in a variable, I can recommend [URL-Parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse)

```
const Url = require('url-parse');
const url = new Url('https://github.com/foo/bar');
```

According to the documentation, it extracts the following parts:

> The returned url instance contains the following properties:
>
> protocol: The protocol scheme of the URL (e.g. http:).
>   slashes: A boolean which indicates whether the protocol is followed by two forward slashes (//).
>   auth: Authentication information portion (e.g. username:password).
>   username: Username of basic authentication.
>   password: Password of basic authentication.
>   host: Host name with port number.
>   hostname: Host name without port number.
>   port: Optional port number.
>   pathname: URL path.
>   query: Parsed object containing query string, unless parsing is set to false.
>   hash: The "fragment" portion of the URL including the pound-sign (#).
>   href: The full URL.
>   origin: The origin of the URL.