# If statement not work jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, pathname

I have this url:

```
csumb/index.php?page=consultanta
```

I try to compare 2 links but this code do the same thing if I change my link and I refresh the page.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var a = "csumb/index.php?page=consultanta";

if(pathname == a) {
    $("body").html("rahat");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(pathname);` to see whats actually in it? I suspect you're missing a slash at the start of the string.

Comment: `location.pathname` gives you the *path*, e.g., `/`. `?page=consultanta` is a *query string*.

Comment: Take a look here for the different parts of the URL you have access to in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple parts to `location` (or `window.location`, to use the literal reference):

https://packagist.org/search/?search_query%5Bquery%5D=symfony

Using `console.log(location)` directly into the Chrome console, it gives the following properties (plus some other stuff):

```
hash: ""
host: "packagist.org"
hostname: "packagist.org"
href: "https://packagist.org/search/?search_query%5Bquery%5D=symfony&page=4"
origin: "https://packagist.org"
pathname: "/search/"
port: ""
protocol: "https:"
search: "?search_query%5Bquery%5D=symfony&page=4"
```

What you're really after is:

```
var pathname = location.pathname + location.search;
var a = "/csumb/index.php?page=consultanta";
//       ^ Note the / at the beginning
```

The filename, if in the URL, will be in `location.pathname`, so `index.php` will not need to be added separately either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var search = window.location.search;
var a = "/csumb/index.php?page=consultanta";

if((pathname + search) == a) {
    $("body").html("rahat");
}
```

Comment: `location.pathname` does not include any URL variables so this won't work.

Comment: I tried your code but I have the same result for diferent pages.

Comment: Can you add this line to the code and get me the log. `console.log(document.location);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [===](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) operator and you need to add a "/".

Also you need `window.location.search`:

```
var a = "/csumb/index.php?page=consultanta";
var search = window.location.search;
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

if(pathname + search === a) {
    $("body").html("rahat");
}
```

Comment: Removed it from the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not jQuery, please edit the title to javascript. the jQuery part is not used in if statement. window.location.pathname returns something like /csumb/index.php without parameters. so if you like to check  the pathname with other parameters, you will need to do this :

```
var path = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
```

Comment: I tried tthis: var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var search = window.location.search;
var a = "http://localhost/csumb/index.php?page=consultanta";
 
 if((pathname + search) == a) {
   $("#outPopUp").fadeIn(3000);
}
else
{
 $("#outPopUp").fadeOut(3000);
}

Comment: you should not use localhost then! just try this code :    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   var search = window.location.search;
   var a = "/csumb/index.php?page=consultanta";
   if((pathname + search) == a)
    { $("body").fadeIn(3000);alert ('ee');  }
   else { $("body").fadeOut(3000); }