# Do I need to specify a webpage's url?

Tags: html

I've uploaded several files to my server and it's really quite baffling. The home page is saved as `index.html`, and when I type in the URL of said page it miraculously, and quite successfully shows the right page. What about my other pages? I have linked to them from the home page with the following code:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/about/">About Us</a>`

How does my html file, presumably called about.html, supposed to know that its URL is "http://www.example.com/about/"? I am dubbing this "The Unanswered Question" because I have looked at numerous examples of metadata and there is nothing about specifying the URL of a page.

Comment: DirectoryIndex in your `.htaccess` is what controls this (the reason index.html automatically works as the home page), I believe. Unless you're doing url rewriting, you'll need to add the extension (ie `about.html`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what type of server you are running.

### Static web servers

If it is the simplest kind of static file server with no URL [aliasing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) or [rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) then URLs will map directly to files:

If your "web root" was `/home/youruser/www/`, then that means:

```
http://www.example.com -> /home/youruser/www/
```

And any paths (everything after the domain name) translate directly to paths under that web root:

```
http://www.example.com/about.html -> /home/youruser/www/about.html
```

Usually web servers will look automatically for an "index.html" file if no **file** is specified (i.e. the URL ends in a `/`):

```
http://www.example.com/ -> /home/youruser/www/index.html
http://www.example.com/about/ -> /home/youruser/www/about/index.html
```

In Apache, the filename searched for is configurable with the [`DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.txt /cgi-bin/index.pl
```

That means that every request to a path that ends in a `/` (and to add yet another rule, under some common settings it will [automatically append](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) a `/` if the path is the name of a directory, for example 'about'):

```
http://www.example.com/ -> /home/youruser/www/index.html
                        -> or /home/youruser/www/index.txt
                        -> or /home/youruser/www/cgi-bin/index.pl
```

### Web servers with path interpretation

There are too many different types of servers which perform this functionality to list them all, but the basic idea is that a request to the server is captured by a program and then the program decides what to output based on the path.

For example, a program might perform different routes for basic matching rules:

```
*.(gif|jpg|css|js) -> look for and return the file from /home/user/static
blog/*             -> send to a "blog" program to generate the resulting page
                      using a combination of templates and database resources
```

Examples include:

- Python
- Java Servlets
- Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)s (used by Wordpress, etc.)

### Links in HTML pages

Finally, the links in the HTML pages just change the URL of the location bar.  The behavior of an HTML link is the same regardless of what exists on the server.  And the server, in turn, only responds to HTTP requests and only produces resources (HTML, images, CSS, JavaScript, etc.), which your browser consumes.  The server only serves those resources and does not have any special behavioral link with them.

- **Absolute URLs** are those that start with a [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) (such as `http:` as you have done).  The whole content of the location bar will be replaced with this when the user clicks the link.
- **Domain relative URLs** are those that start with a forward slash (`/`).  Everything after the domain name will be replaced with the contents of this link.
- **Relative URLs** are everything else.  Everything after the last directory (`/`) in the URL will be replaced with the contents of this link.

Examples:

- My page on "mydomain.com" can link to your site using the `<a href="http://www.example.com/about/">Example.com about</a>` just as you have done.
- If I change my links to `<a href="/about">about</a>` then it will link to `mydomain.com` instead.

### An answer your question

> How does my html file, presumably called about.html, supposed to know that its URL is "http://www.example.com/about/"?

First, **the file itself has no idea what its URL is.** Unless:

- the HTML was dynamically generated using a program.  Most server-side languages provide a way to get this.
- after the page is served, client-side scripts [can also detect the current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path/6944772#6944772)

Second, **if the URL is `/about` and the file is actually `about.html` then you probably have some kind of rewriting going on.**  Remember that paths, in their simplest, are literal translations and `/about` is not the same as `about.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `/about.html` to link to the page

Comment: Yeah, I already did that, but I don't expect people to be able to type in the URL and achieve the same results.

Comment: Well, I'm rather used to having to tell it exactly what to do. If it's in the same directory then there's no way of it knowing which page is which, or whether to pull a page up at all when someone types in a correct url.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it's better for URLs in your documents to be *relative*, so that you don't have to change them in the event you change the domain or the files location.

For example, if you move it from localhost to your hosted server.

In your example, instead of [`www.example.com/about.html`](http://www.example.com/about.html) use [`/about.html`](http://www.example.com/about.html).

Answer (score 0):

Given the link above you would need a about page named index.html located in a directory named about for your example to work. That is however not common practice.

Comment: No, not necessarily. They could add an .htaccess file in the root instructing Apache to use `Options +MultiViews`

Comment: True was just thinking it could be configured through the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, but here is some information. Any file named "index" is the default display page for any directory(folder) when trying to view that directory.

All files in a folder are always relative to that directory. So if your link is in a file, within a different directory, then you must type in that directory along with the file. If it is the same directory, then there is no need to type in that directory, just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

`about.html` doesn't know what it's URL is, its the `index.html` file that calls your `about.html` file.

When you're in any given directory, linking to other pages within that directory is done via a simple relative link:

```
<a href="/about.html">About Us</a>
```

Moving up a directory, assuming you're in a sub folder (users) perhaps you can use the `..` operator to navigate up one directory:

```
<a href="../about.html">About Us</a>
```

In your case your about page is in the same directory as the page you're linking from so it just goes to the right page.

Additionally (and I think this may be what you're asking) if you have:

> about.html
>   about.php
>   about.phtml
>   about.jpg

for example, and you visit `http://www.yoursite.com/about` it will automatically bring up the html page and the other pages should be referenced explicitly somewhere if you want them to be used.