# change part of the url text and reload page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to make an a tag link that includes part of the current url?

I would use it to change language but stay on the current page!

If I am on:

```
www.mysite.com/contact
```

and I press on:

```
<a>FR</a>
```

the generated link would be:

```
www.mystie.com/fr/contact
```

Kind regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path

Answer (score 0):

you can try with some like

```
function changeLng(lang) {

  // remove language '/fr/' or '/es/' if exists
  var path = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/[a-z]{2}/, '');
  // reload the page same url with the lang prefix
  window.location.href = '/' + lang + path;
}
```

the link can be

```
<a href="javascript:changeLng('fr');">FR</a>
<a href="javascript:changeLng('es');">ES</a>
<a href="javascript:changeLng('en');">EN</a>
```

this converts any url to lang specific, sample

- `/contact` to `/fr/contact`
- `/about` to `/fr/about`

### update

for remove the lang part is simple

```
function removeLng() {
  // remove language
  var path = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/[a-z]{2}/, '');
  window.location.href = path;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. The only thing is that it generates: [link](http://example.com/fr//contact) with twice //...

Comment: ...and how do I get back from example.com/fr/contact to example.com/contact ? Thanks

Comment: @iolli only remove the `+ '/'` part and the las `\/` in the regex check the update. I have not tried the code but you now  have a idea how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<a href="fr/contact" id="myLink">FR</a>
```

Now get the url from javascript

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();         
    var url = document.url;                         // get current page url
    url = url.substr(0, url.indexOf('/'));          // get substring from url
    url += "/" + $(this).attr("href");              // add href of a tag to url 
    window.location.href = url;                     // locate the page to url

});
```