# Javascript code to check URL content and keep only one thing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a code in javascript which is about IMDB.

When the page loads i want the code to check the URL in the browser bar

and take into a variable only one thing
For example when we join

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0241527/?ref_=nv_sr_1

it should take ONLY the  ***tt0241527***

and put it into a variable called searchTerm.

I have searched some posts but i couldnt help myself.

Is it possible for someone to help me test it in my chrome console ??

Lets say that i use this

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
console.log(pathname);
```

its showing this

```
/title/tt0241527/
```

but i want to delete /title/ and the last  /

That's my problem

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hum. Did you try anything ? What's the problem ? Assuming you don't know regular expressions, you could `split` `location.pathname`, no ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret the problem is that i dont know a lot about javascript and dont know where to start.

Comment: Start by searching. For example "parse URL javascript"

Comment: you could, for instance check these questions. Your answer is in them:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re certain (i.e. already made sure) that `window.location.pathname` is something like `/title/tt0241527/`, you could just remove the undesired characters using `replace` with a regular expression:

```
var searchTerm = window.location.pathname.replace(/(\/title\/|\/$)/g,'');
console.log(searchTerm); // e.g. === 'tt0241527'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! this is what i was trying to do!

Comment: That’s great and you’re welcome. Of course, this is no actual URL parsing. You also could [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) `location.href` with a more sophisticated regex.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "ID" it's always after the `/title/` path, you should do the following:

```
var str = location.pathname;
var l = str.split("/");
var id = l[l.indexOf("title")+1];
```

You could use regex, but if you are new to javascript, better do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

As long as this is a consistent url pattern:

```
var url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0241527/?ref_=nv_sr_1";
```

Get the length of the string

```
var len = url.length;
```

Remove the http://

```
url = url.substr(7, len-7);
```

Split up string into array based on the forward slash

```
var urlArray = url.split("/");

var domain = urlArray[0];
var title = urlArray[1];
var searchTerm = urlArray[2];
var queryString = urlArray[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace with regex

```
window.location.pathname.replace(/\/title\/|\/$/g,"")
```