# How to get a part of a url string with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, no-framework

I have this url, for example:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render#main_7%7Cmonth
```

I need to get ONLY `calendar` with or witout `/`

Why in pure JavaScript?
I want to put it in a bookmark, so i cant use any kind of JS.Framework...

Some of you could say that post is duplicated. Thats why you dont use the search-tool nor read the entire question.
Thanks for other who really read everything.

PD:Yeah, i've readed this solution.. this does not fit me. [JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path)

Comment: The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6944834/1599191) on that question does fit what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split function to divide string to array:

```
"https://www.google.com/calendar/render#main_7%7Cmonth".split('/')[3];
```

Comment: It has to be everything in one line, because in "BookMark" does not let me use more than one command. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `calendar` is always on the same position you could do

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/render#main_7%7Cmonth';
var calendar = url.split('/')[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

(I'm a bit sad answering this).

`var whatyouwant = url.split('/')[3];`

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/calendar/render#main_7%7Cmonth";
var split_url = url.split('/');
for(var i=0; i < split_url.length; i++)
  if(split_url[i] == 'calendar')
    alert("It's a calendar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for calendar and extract the remainder of the string -

```
var s = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/render#main_7%7Cmonth';
var o = s.indexOf('calendar');
if (o !== -1) {
    // Found calendar at offset o
    console.log(o);
    console.log(s.substr(o));
}
```