# Javascript, current link?

Tags: javascript, mobile

So I am current redirecting users who are on mobiles using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width <= 720) {
        window.location = "m/index.php";
    }
</script>
```

But, I want to know the code for the current link of the page, then automatically place it within the code itself. So its basically like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width <= 720) {
        window.location = "m/CurrentPageURL.php";
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be grand :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path)

Comment: you want the file name??

Comment: Use `if (screen.width <= 720) {
        window.location = "m/"+location.pathname+location.search;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if (location.pathname.substr(0, 3) !== "/m/" && screen.width <= 720) {
    location.href = "/m" + location.pathname;
}
```

It checks that you're not already in the `/m/` subdir and then redirects there if appropriate.  This should work on any page in your site, as long as you have the relevant mobile version of the page in question.

To do the opposite, just add this...

```
if (location.pathname.substr(0, 3) === "/m/" && screen.width > 720) {
    location.href = location.pathname.substr(3);
}
```

I would like to add that there are much better ways to handle mobile detection.  For example, my phone has a higher resolution than my desktop monitor, but is only a 5" screen.  Realistically it should be redirected to a mobile site (if the site is not responsive), but with this code it wouldn't be.

Just something to bear in mind.

Comment: thank you for your help!
and I will take that into account :)

also how would I do this in reverse, for example if someone found my mobile link on a desktop how can i redirect them to my normal homepage?

Comment: No problem.  I've just added a bit of extra code to do the opposite, using the same kind of screen width detection.