# Get subdomain on server without iron router in collection hook

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm using angular-meteor to write a multi-tenant app, so I'm not using Iron router.  I would like to be able to get the subdomain that the user is accessing the page from within a collection hook. (I am using the separate collection hooks package)  This parameter will only be used if a trusted superadmin is accessing the page over SSL so it will be trusted input.  I just can't for the life of me figure out how to get this.  I tried using this.connection.httpHeaders, however, this only works in publish and meteor subscribe methods. It must be so simple, but I just can't figure it out. I'm asking here, because there is probably someone who knows much better than I and could point it out in a second.

Comment: You can just this in js using `window.location`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6944772/2805154

Comment: I'm talking about server side, not client side.