# Splitting string by third instance?

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/level1/level2"
```

I would like to split the URL in 3 levels by the character `/`. I tried:

```
var array = url.split('/');
```

But the output is this:

```
['http:','','www.example.com','level1','level2']
```

I would like this:

```
['http://www.example.com','level1','level2']
```

I tried `url.split('/')[2]` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You _don't_ want to split at the 3rd instance, but parse a URL in JavaScript.

Comment: I recommend to look at [JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6944744/218196)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not parse it properly

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/level1/level2"

var a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = url;

a.protocol; // http:
a.host;     // www.example.com
a.pathname; // /level1/level2

var parts = a.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean);
parts.unshift(a.protocol + '//' + a.host); // ['http://www.example.com','level1','level2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo 
Thank you so much! your answer is really simple and clean (I did not know the methods to parse the URL), but there is a small error in your answer ... (really small :))

Your output is this:

```
['http://www.example.com','','level1','level2']
```

So to have my output (3 levels):

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/level1/level2"

var a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = url;

a.protocol; // http:
a.host;     // www.example.com
a.pathname; // /level1/level2

var parts = a.pathname.split('/');
parts.shift();  // added this line ------------------
parts.unshift(a.protocol + '//' + a.host); 

document.write(parts);
```

with `parts.shift();` added before the method `unshift()` , in this way the output is true:

```
['http://www.example.com','level1','level2']
```

Forgive me if I'm allowed to correct you :)

if I am wrong please tell me :)
Thanks again!

Comment: Didn't notice that, it's because the URL is `/level1/level2`, so when splitting on `/` there's an entry for the parts before the first `/` which is empty. Another way to fix it is to trim off the `/` at the start and end of the `pathname`, or filter it out, and I'm adding that to the answer