# Regex append characters to a substring

Tags: javascript, regex

My string comes in two flavours-

```
var a = /aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663?sg=1#/propertyinfo
```

or

```
var a = /aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663#/propertyinfo
```

I want to append the content that comes after aid/ and before ? or # with "-test". In either of the above scenarios the result would be f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663-test

hence

```
a = /aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663-test#/propertyinfo
```

or

```
a = = /aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663-test?sg=1#/propertyinfo
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: [JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6944772/1115360) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/bO0qY1/2).

Regular expression `/\/aid\/[0-9A-F]*/i` and replacement expression `$0-test`.

JavaScript is a little bit different than just plain regular expression antics, so here you go;

```js
var a = "/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663?sg=1#/propertyinfo";
alert(a.replace(/(\/aid\/[0-9A-F]*)/i, "$1-test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

given your examples I guess that string after `/aid/` is some kind of md5 hash

this should work for you:

```
'/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663#/propertyinfo'.replace(new RegExp('/aid/([a-f0-9]{32})'), '$1-test');
```

if you don't want to be that much specific about length, you can try the following:

```
'/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663#/propertyinfo'.replace(new RegExp('/aid/([a-f0-9]+)'), '$1-test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `String.replace` function:

```
var a = '/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663sg=1#/propertyinfo',
    result = a.replace(/aid\/([^?#]+)(?=\?|#)/, "aid/$1-test");

console.log(result); // /aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663-test?sg=1#/propertyinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replacing directly the `#` or `?` so the regex is nice and simple. :)

```js
var a = "/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663?sg=1#/propertyinfo";
var b = "/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663#/propertyinfo";

console.log(a.replace(/([\?#])/,"-test$1"));
console.log(b.replace(/([\?#])/,"-test$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = '/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663?sg=1#/propertyinfo';

a.replace(/(\/aid\/.+)(\?sg=1)(#\/propertyinfo)/,function(text,c,d,e){
    return c+'-test'+e;
})
//Output: "/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663-test#/propertyinfo"

a.replace(/(\/aid\/.+)(\?sg=1#\/propertyinfo)/,function(text,c,d){
    return c+'-test'+d;
});
//Output: "/aid/f82eb514073124cd10d468b74eee5663-test?sg=1#/propertyinfo"
```