# Extract part of URL with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL that will always be in either this format

`http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo`

`http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo`

`http://sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo`

`http://www.sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo`

I'd like to use Regex to extract `bar` from the url, regardless of the format.

I am using JavaScript.

I tried to break the url up using something like

```
var x = 'http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo`'
x.split(/^((http[s]?):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/g)
```

but this doesn't really work nor does it help as I seem to get an array or items when I really just need the value at `bar`

Comment: If you know input is a URL do `match` on [`^.*\/([^\/]+)\/[^\/]*\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/PDOpfM/1)

Comment: Why don't you just split by "`/`" and take the second to last ?

Comment: How would you handle `.../foo/bar/boo/`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That is not in OP's examples, but you can still filter by removing the empty strings in the resulting array.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts My bad then :)

Comment: regex is the wrong tool for the job here. Use a parser.

Comment: Added regex and non-regex way along with examples. Tell me if it works or not. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll list both regex and non regex way. Surprisingly the regex way seems shorter.

## Regex Way

The regex to find bar and boo is this `/.*\/(.*)\/(.*)$/` which is short, precise and exactly what you need.

Let's put into practice,

```
const params = "http://www.sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo".match(/.*\/(.*)\/(.*)$/)
```

This results in,

```
params;
["http://www.sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo","bar","boo"]
```

Just access it like `params[0]` and `params[1]`.

**Regex Explanation:**

[image]

**Extended Version:**

The regex can be extended more to grab the `/bar/foo/` pattern with a ending slash like this,

```
.*\/\b(.*)\/\b(.*)(\/?)$
```

Which means,
[image]

and it can be further extended, but let's keep it simple for now.

## Non Regex Way

Use native methods like `.split()`,

```
function getLastParam(str, targetIndex = 1) {
  const arr = str
                .split("/") // split by slash
                .filter(e=>e); // remove empty array elements
  return arr[arr.length - targetIndex];
}
```

Let's test it out quickly for different cases

```
[
  "http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo",
  "http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo",
  "http://sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo",
  "http://www.sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo",
  "http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo/",
  ".../bar/boo"
].map(e => {
  console.log({ input: e, output: getLastParam(e, 1) });
});
```

This will yield in following,

```
{input: "http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo", output: "boo"}
{input: "http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo", output: "boo"}
{input: "http://sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo", output: "boo"}
{input: "http://www.sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo", output: "boo"}
{input: "http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo/", output: "boo"}
{input: ".../bar/boo", output: "boo"}
```

If you want `bar`, then use 2 for `targetIndex` instead. It will get the second last. In which case, `getLastParam(str, 2)` would result in `bar`.

## Speed stuff

Here is the small benchmark stuff, http://jsbench.github.io/#a6bcecaa60b7d668636f8f760db34483

```
getLastParamNormal: 5,203,853 ops/sec
getLastParamRegex: 6,619,590 ops/sec
```

Well, it doesn't matter. But nonetheless, it's interesting.

Answer (score 5):

```
var el = document.createElement('a');
el.href = "http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo";
var importantPart = el.pathname.split('/')[2];
console.log(importantPart);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dcyo4ph5/1/

sources: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/ & [JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path)

I guess this doesn't use regex. So that's maybe not what you want.

Comment: This is better than regex.

Comment: @SalmanA unless you're here with a less trivial problem looking for an answer that answers the question

Answer (score 1):

Split and slice will do that as simple as this, where `split('/')` creates an array and `slice(-2)[0]` will pick the first `[0]` of the last two `(-2)`.

*With `replace(/\/$/, "")` you get rid of any trailing slash (showed in 4th sample below)*

Stack snippet

```js
var x = 'http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo'
console.log( x.split('/').slice(-2)[0] );

var x = 'http://www.sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo'
console.log( x.split('/').slice(-2)[0] );

var x = 'http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo'
console.log( x.split('/').slice(-2)[0] );

// and this one will trim trailing slash
var x = 'http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo/'
console.log( x.replace(/\/$/, "").split('/').slice(-2)[0] );
```

---

Or maybe just `reverse` the array and get the 2nd item (`[1]` as array is zero based)

```
var x = 'http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo/'
console.log( x.split('/').reverse()[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex. Anchor elements have an API that breaks down the URL for you. You can then split the `pathname` to get the path

```js
function parse(path) {
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = path;

  return a.pathname.split('/')[2];
}

console.log(parse('http://domain.tld/foo/bar/boo'));
console.log(parse('http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo'));
console.log(parse('http://sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo'));
console.log(parse('http://www.sub.domain.tld/foo/bar/boo'));
```