# How to get site name from string in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out on how to strip everything and only keep the site name.

So given:

```
var url = "https://www.example.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=50&status=publish";
```

How would I get "`example`"?

Not familiar with regex.

Comment: Look at `location.host` or `location.hostname` and strip off the domain extension

Comment: @Turnip yes I've looked at that answer but it uses host and doesn't give me the name only https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944772/1018804

Comment: @Taplar as per the other comment, I've looked atusing host as per stackoverflow.com/a/6944772/1018804 but I can't figure out on how to only get the actual name and not the wwww

Comment: @rob.m Read the second part of the accepted answer. Then read the second most upvoted answer.

Comment: @Taplar I don't, otherwise I wouldn't have asked

Comment: Take a look at String.prototype.substring and String.prototype.substr .  These are basic javascript string manipulation methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the URL object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

```js
var address = "https://www.example.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=50&status=publish";
var url = new URL(address);
var hostname = url.hostname;
var hostTokens = hostname.split('\.');

console.log(hostTokens[1]); // example

console.log({
  hash         : url.hash,
  host         : url.host,
  hostname     : url.hostname,
  href         : url.href,
  origin       : url.origin,
  password     : url.password,
  pathname     : url.pathname,
  port         : url.port,
  protocol     : url.protocol,
  search       : url.search,
  username     : url.username
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you need to support sub-domain, you can modify the following function.

```js
var addresses = [ 'https://www.example.it', 'https://mail.example.it' ];

addresses.forEach(address => console.log(parseDomain(address)));

function parseDomain(address) {
  var url = new URL(address);
  var hostTokens = url.hostname.split('\.');
  var result = {
    'Domain' : hostTokens[hostTokens.length - 2],
    'Top-Level Domain' : hostTokens[hostTokens.length - 1]
  };
  if (hostTokens.length > 2 && hostTokens[0] !== 'www') {
    result['Sub-Domain'] = hostTokens[0];
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: ok am I correct by saying that basically this line var hostTokens = hostname.split('\.'); says get rid of everything before and after the dot?

Comment: as others are pointing out, how about a sub domain like www.example.subdomain.com?

Comment: No, it means separate the string by its dots. You will get the array: `['www', 'example', 'it']`

Comment: @rob.m In your case, you did not ask for some fancy kitchen sink. If you need the example part, grab the hostname, split it, and grab the second token.

Comment: oh ok, sure, split creates an array. Makes total sense. so [1] is basically the array index at position 1. It's true I haven't asked and to be honest, I don't it. But just to make it more complete for future users, if you find time maybe a solution for sub domains would be great. Anyway, thanks a lot. Will accept it as soon as it let me.

Comment: @rob.m In the second example, you can work backwards to get the relevant pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the **domain** by using the combination of [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) without using **regex**, the host name will return `www.example.com`, so if we apply `.split('.')` on it then it'll return an array `['www','example','com']`, using `[1]` I am taking the **example** part only, Hope it helps :)

```js
var url = "https://www.example.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=50&status=publish";
var domain = (new URL(url)).hostname.split('.')[1]
console.log(domain)
```

**For subdomain capture**,

```js
var url = "https://www.abc.example.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=50&status=publish";
var subdomain = (new URL(url)).hostname.split('.')[1];
var domain = (new URL(url)).hostname.split('.')[2];
console.log(subdomain, domain)
```

Comment: I see, so with hostname you only get the www.example.com, then basically say get of all dots, can you explain what [1] does?

Comment: Note that this won't work with a url that contains a subdomain as the split would occur after the subdomain and not the hostname.

Comment: @rob.m, `[1]` is accessing the second index of the array that .`split` returns. Remember that array indexes start at 0, not 1. The array would look like so: `[0] => 'www', [1] => 'example', [2] => 'com'`.

Comment: @rob.m **Edited** my answer and added some description how I get `example` value from the url

Comment: @AlwaysSunny thanks a lot, I don't need it for my case but what about bread comment?

Comment: @rob.m **Edited** again mate :) best of luck

Comment: superb! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
function getSiteName() {
  const fullUrlSplit = window.location.host.split(".");
  if (fullUrlSplit[0] !== "www")
    return fullUrlSplit[0];
  return fullUrlSplit[1];   
}
```

This will work as long as there is no subdomain.