# window.location.href - just need to get the last bit of the url in the line below (I dont need the host details)

Tags: javascript, url

How can I just get the last bit of the url in the line below (I dont need the host details)

> window.location.href=="https://xxx.yyy.nnn/directory/index.asp"

[*i.e i'm only interetsed in the "directory/index.asp" part of the url.*]

and can I 'OR' two stements together in an if statment (I know its not right until I have an answer above

```
if (window.location.href=="directory/index.asp") || (window.location.href=="directory/page.html")
    {runSsomecode();}
```

thanks

Comment: You're looking for [`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname). And you can do that "or" if you remove the inner parens:  `if (a == "b" || a == "c") ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - Get Portion of URL Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path)