# is there a way to get the last digit in a URL in NUXT/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have an API(SWAPI), I want to view a single result, maybe persons or planets, but the API doesn't return a single ID, instead it returns a complete URL to view a single item, the url looks like this

```
"url": "http://swapi.dev/api/people/1/"
```

how do I get that last digit so I can dynamically be calling it as an ID in my dynamic pages

Comment: the base url is `https://swapi.dev/api` just build up what you want to query, from values passed to the page i.e with this.$route.params, or this.$route.query etc if you need parse it there is plenty of examples on the web https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path

Answer (score 0):

Well, JavaScript can access the current URL in parts. So 
`window.location.pathname` will return `/api/people/1/`
Then the dirty way is to use `slice()` method to remove the `/api/people/`