# How to make an option selected based on the page (URL)?

Tags: jquery

i have created a dropdown where i have a dropdown of multiple records of users. When i select first option, the page redirect to the link which open details page of user. Now, i want to set the selected user inside select option field. here is my code

```
<select class="user">

<?php foreach($user as $key => $value): ?>

    <optgroup label=  <?php echo $key; ?> >

        <?php foreach($value as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="key-select-option">
                <?php echo $row['name'] .' & '. $row['roll_number'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </optgroup>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>


$('.user').on('change', function() {
        var userId = $(this).val();

        var url = 'https://localhost/user/' + userId;
        window.location.href = url;
});
```

This code redirect me to another page but how to make this selected inside your dropdown?

Comment: `$(".user").val(the value you want to set)`

Comment: set selected with the php code if the id matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [get the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path) using `window.location.pathname`. Then split that by `/` (`.split('/')`) and get the last value of that array (`[array.length - 1]`). Finally, set the value in JS using `.val('userId')`. Putting it all together:

```
let parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
let userId = parts[parts.length-1];
$('.user').val(userId);

$('.user').on('change', function() {
  var userId = $(this).val();

  var url = 'https://localhost/user/' + userId;
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

---

This is also possible in PHP. To get the last portion of the URL:

```
// $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'https://localhost/user/1234';

$array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$userId = end($array);

echo $userId;
```

Then you can use this and update your template to set the `selected` attribute if the value matches:

```
<?php
  $array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $userId = end($array);
?>

<select class="user">

<?php foreach($user as $key => $value): ?>

    <optgroup label="<?php echo $key; ?>">

        <?php foreach($value as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="key-select-option" <?php echo $row['id'] == $userId ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                <?php echo $row['name'] .' & '. $row['roll_number'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </optgroup>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note I also added double quotes around your `optgroup` label because they were missing.