# Website with username in path like: website.com/username

Tags: html, firebase, url, google-cloud-firestore

Im quite new to website development and HTML, and Im developing a website where users create an account with a unique username using Firebase and Cloud Firestore

Now I want to add a page that recognizes the username from the url and loads the users "Homepage". Like in this example: https://www.instagram.com/username/

URL is website.com/username.
Now I want to retrieve "username" and load the users info.

How should I proceed to make this? I use Webflow to create my website.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944744/javascript-get-portion-of-url-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `window.location.pathname` to get what the `username` in the case where the route is `website.com/username`. You can then do some logic using the user name to get user data from firbase.

Comment: Where should I do this logic to avoid redirecting to "404 page not found"?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont know how web flow works, but this might be helpful. https://university.webflow.com/lesson/custom-code-embed

Comment: Thank you for your help. Despite your answer being really simple it actually did help. I think I was just a little lost and thinking too complicated. Now I think I know how to make it work. Thank you

Comment: @Peter I am glad it helped. Thanks too!

Comment: If you're using Firebase Hosting to serve the website, you'd configure a rewrite to make sure all URLs map to the page that handles them. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites. If you use another hosting provider, it'll have a similar configurtion.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes this seems like it! Thank you. Would you mind submitting an answer and elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebase Hosting to serve the website, you'd configure a rewrite to make sure all URLs map to the page that handles them. See the documentation on how to [configure rewrites for a single-page application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites).

If you use another hosting provider, it'll have a similar configuration.